# How to create a text box in Wordpress css that includes bullet points and bold text

Tags: css, wordpress

I've tried editing the text editor code within the Wordpress post
    Ohio State Learning Standards
    High School American History

- Topic: Historical Thinking and Skills, Content Statement 4
- Topic: Industrialization and Progressivism (1877-1920), Content 
      Statements 12 and 13

and I've tried editing the external CSS, but everytime I make text bold or create bullet points, it breaks the code.

**External CSS(within wordpress theme)**

```
.textbox {padding:2px 6px 4px 6px; color: #555555; 
   background-color: #eeeeee; 
   border: #dddddd 2px solid
 }
```

**Text Editor**
    Ohio State Learning Standards
    High School American History

- Topic: Historical Thinking and Skills, Content Statement 4
- Topic: Industrialization and Progressivism (1877-1920), Content 
      Statements 12 and 13
- Topic: Prosperity, Depression and the New Deal (1919-1941), Content 
      Statements 17, 18, and 19
- Topic: Social Transformations in the United States (1945-1994), Content 
      Statements 28 and 30

```
<strong>High School American Government</strong>
<ul>
   <li>Topic: Role of the People, Content Statement 17</li>
</ul></p>
```

Comment: you have an extra closing `</p>` tag at the end. That is breaking the code

Answer (score 0):

You write: "I've tried editing the external CSS, but everytime I make text bold or create bullet points, it breaks the code."

If you mean you added properties to this rule..

```
.textbox {padding:2px 6px 4px 6px; color: #555555; 
   background-color: #eeeeee; 
   border: #dddddd 2px solid
 }
```

..., you might have forgotten to close the `border` setting with a semicolon when you added additional lines:

```
.textbox {padding:2px 6px 4px 6px; color: #555555; 
   background-color: #eeeeee; 
   border: #dddddd 2px solid;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
```

Also, that `.textbox` class is not used anywhere in the HTML code you posted (?)